# Difference between sorted and sortBy

Tags: performance, list, scala, collections, time-complexity

According to doc for List

```
def  sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: math.Ordering[B]): List[A] 
Sorts this list according to an Ordering.


def sortBy[B](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit ord: math.Ordering[B]): List[A]

Sorts this List according to the Ordering which results from transforming an implicitly given Ordering with a transformation function.
```

When would you use one and when would you use the other?  Does one cover a scenario the other does not?

Answer (score 6):

For sortBy you can supply custom function that produces elements used for sorting (e.g. sort by the length string) whereas for sorted you cant:

```
val xs = List("aa", "b")
// xs: List[String] = List(aa, b)
xs.sortBy{ str => str.length }
// List[String] = List(b, aa)

// now usual lexicographical sorting
xs.sorted
// List[String] = List(aa, b)
xs.sortBy(x => x)
// List[String] = List(aa, b)
xs.sortBy(identity)
// List[String] = List(aa, b)
```

as you can see, last three lines are identical in their result

Comment: `xs.sorted(math.Ordering.by[String, Int](_.length))`

Comment: @Debilski you are cheating! ;-)

Comment: @om-nom-nom sorted you can pass a custom object. So when is a custom object better than a custom function?

Comment: @MoreThanFive - It's usually easier to specify the function.

Answer (score 3):

You would use `sorted` with an `Ordering` if you have to consider multiple cases. Suppose we want to sort the following list having shortest strings at the beginning.

```
val xs = "aa" :: "b" :: "bb" :: "a" :: Nil

xs.sortBy(_.length)
> List[String] = List(b, a, aa, bb)
```

If we want to additionally sort them alphabetically, when they have the same length, we could use `sorted`

```
xs.sorted(math.Ordering[(Int, String)].on((x: String) => (x.length, x)))
> List[String] = List(a, b, aa, bb)
```

But then again, we could have used

```
xs.sortBy(x => (x.length, x))
> List[String] = List(a, b, aa, bb)
```

as well.

The idea is that you can supply `Ordering` type classes for your own types and then a simple `xs.sorted` with such an implicit `Ordering` will work for the most common use cases.

Comment: I am confused. You say you should be an alphabetical sort but your results are not.

Comment: I want to only sort them alphabetically when they have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @om-nom-nom's answer, [here](http://ideone.com/QuTIWH) is an example of typical usage of the two:

```
val xs = List(4, 2, 3, 1)
val ys = List((1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3))
println(xs.sorted)       // List(1, 2, 3, 4)
println(ys.sortBy(_._1)) // List((1,1), (2,3), (3,2))
```